# filtrar dataframe por linha python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython-notebook

Olá, possuo esse DataFrame com **centenas de milhares de linhas**, quero filtrar de forma que seleção seja apenas as linhas desejadas, no caso linhas mais atuais, segue um exemplo do que quero:

a coluna DT_REFER representa a data que foi atualizado, a coluna VERSAO a versão do doc atual, DT_FIM_EXERC a data que a linha representa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero filtrar através da ultima data do DT_REFER junto com a ultima versão do VERSAO, me retornando isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo iniciar a pesquisa, correlacionar as colunas.

Obrigado

Comment: Qual a expressão de filtro que você está usando? A coluna `DT_REFER` já é do tipo data ou é string? Caso seja string, converta usando `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: não estavam no formato data, acabei convertendo, obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o groupby + max

Tipos de dados no arquivo excel:

```
df.info()
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------        --------------  -----         
 0   DT_REFER      6 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   VERSAO        6 non-null      int64         
 2   DENON_CIA     6 non-null      object        
 3   DT_FIM_EXERC  6 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 4   CD_CONTA      6 non-null      object        
 5   DS_CONTA      6 non-null      object        
 6   VL_CONTA      6 non-null      float64
```

Caso a sua coluna `DT_REFER` não esteja como data você pode fazer a conversão(no caso o arquivo que eu usei ja fez essa conversão):

```
df['DT_REFER'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT_REFER'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Data frame:

```
df
    DT_REFER    VERSAO    DENON_CIA           DT_FIM_EXERC    CD_CONTA    DS_CONTA                                    VL_CONTA
0   2011-12-31    2       BCO BRADESCO S.A    2011-12-31      2.03.05     provisões técnicas de seguros e previdência 99112321.0
1   2012-12-31    2       BCO BRADESCO S.A    2011-12-31      2.03.05     provisões técnicas de seguros e previdência 99112321.0
2   2017-12-31    2       BCO BRADESCO S.A    2017-12-31      2.06        Outros passivos                             97816824.0
3   2018-12-31    3       BCO BRADESCO S.A    2017-12-31      2.06        Outros passivos                             97816824.0
4   2017-12-31    2       BCO BRADESCO S.A    2017-12-31      2.06.01     Outros passivos                             97816824.0
5   2018-12-31    3       BCO BRADESCO S.A    2017-12-31      2.06.01     Outros passivos                             97816824.0
```

Agrupando e mostrando  resultado:

```
df.groupby('CD_CONTA').max().reset_index()
```

Saída:

```
    CD_CONTA    DT_REFER    VERSAO  DENON_CIA           DT_FIM_EXERC    DS_CONTA                                    VL_CONTA
0   2.03.05    2012-12-31      2    BCO BRADESCO S.A    2011-12-31      provisões técnicas de seguros e previdência 99112321.0
1   2.06       2018-12-31      3    BCO BRADESCO S.A    2017-12-31      Outros passivos                             97816824.0
2   2.06.01    2018-12-31      3    BCO BRADESCO S.A    2017-12-31      Outros passivos                             97816824.0
```

---

**Edit**

Agrupando e mostrando a maior versão e maior data:

```
df.groupby(['DENON_CIA','DT_FIM_EXERC','CD_CONTA','DS_CONTA','VL_CONTA'])[['VERSAO','DT_REFER']].max().reset_index()
```

Comment: Realmente pelo df.info() as colunas datas estavam como object, usei o parse_dates=[0,3] na leitura do csv e o dtype das colunas DT_REFER, DT_FIM_EXERC estão agora como datetime64[ns]. Na consulta que você mencionou está agrupando a coluna CD_CONTA, no caso não é por ela que é definida a consulta, mas sim sim através das colunas DT_REFER e VERSAO, em conjunto são elas que dizem a linhas mais atuais. O que eu quero é a maior data do DT_REFER  com o maior numero do VERSAO e nisso retornando as linhas. obrigado pela atenção

Comment: E agrupar pelo CD_CONTA altera o resultado que você espera? Pois no exemplo que passou isso resolve o seu problema já que ele irá pegar o "maximo" valor dentro dos campos.

Comment: No VL_CONTA pode ter valores diferentes, por isso das colunas DT_REFER e VERSAO estarem na consulta como "principais", esqueci de mencionar na pergunta

Comment: Adicione um exemplo a sua pergunta mostrando isso e o resultado esperado, pois do jeito que você colocou o VL_CONTA está diretamente ligado a conta em si e ela não poderia ser diferente.

Comment: Então, as colunas DT_REFER e VERSAO elas são uma atualização/revisão das colunas: DENOM_CIA, DT_FIM_EXERC, CD_CONTA, DS_CONTA e VL_CONTA, na coluna VL_CONTA pode vim alterado ou não, no dataframe que estou utilizando tem cerca de 800mil linhas, se o filtro for através das colunas DT_REFER e VERSAO vou ter as linhas mais atuais.

Comment: Veja se com a resposta abaixo do `edit` faz o que estava em mente. Abraços!

Comment: Obrigado, aparentemente deu certo, fiz um teste com um dataframe menor, muito obrigado

Comment: Fala Saulo, que bom que resolveu! Caso a resposta tenha solucionado seu problema, considere em marcar a resposta como válida(não é obrigatório mas é uma boa prática para futuros usuários com o mesmo problema). [Veja como](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLkG.jpg). Abraço!

Comment: olá amigo, vim tirar um duvida com você, estou usando a linha que você me recomendou, porém estou enfrentando um problema:
estou usando a seguinte linha: 
df01.groupby(['DENOM_CIA','CD_CONTA','DS_CONTA','VL_CONTA','DT_REFER'])[['DT_INI_EXERC','DT_FIM_EXERC']].max().reset_index() - mas retorna o dataframe completo, se eu retiro a coluna 'VL_CONTA' o retorno do dataframe é exatamente a lógica do que quero, mas necessito da coluna 'VL_CONTA' para gerar um novo dataframe, você sabe dizer o que pode está acontecendo?

Comment: Bom dia, qual problema está enfrentando?

Comment: estou usando a seguinte linha: df01.groupby(['DENOM_CIA','CD_CONTA','DS_CONTA','VL_CONTA','DT_REFER'])[['DT_INI_EXERC','DT_FIM_EXERC']].max().reset_index() - retorna o dataframe completo, se eu retiro a coluna 'VL_CONTA' o retorno do dataframe é exatamente a lógica do que quero, mas necessito da coluna 'VL_CONTA' para gerar um novo dataframe, você sabe dizer o que pode está acontecendo?

Comment: Que data tem nessa variável `DT_INI_EXERC`? Faz o seguinte: sobe um arquivo xlsx com os campos que você utiliza, coloque um resultado que você espera pois fica mais fácil te ajudar. Tentar adivinha o que está ocorrendo é complicado.  Antes você disse que tinha que ser agrupado por: `VERSAO` e `DT_REFER`. Sobe no google drive o arquivo e posta o link aqui.

Comment: Isso, havia dito que necessitava dessas colunas, mas estou percebendo que através dessa forma que quero fica mais claro a consulta, vou subir o xlsx

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t7p2y-obUPGqc2unFpUIN7-qUL3C5TLyaie8MeRoRcA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: um DT_INI_EXERC.max() somente nessa coluna, também daria certo, o problema que to vendo é que a coluna 'VL_CONTA' com ela na consulta retorna todo o DATAFRAME já sem ela na consulta retorna o que quero

Comment: Veja se é o que você precisa: `df.groupby(['DENOM_CIA','CD_CONTA','DS_CONTA','DT_REFER'])[['DT_INI_EXERC','DT_FIM_EXERC','VL_CONTA']].max().reset_index()`. Adicionei o vl_conta onde puxo os valores máximos.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115571/discussion-between-saulo-and-lmonferrari).

Comment: pelo o que entendi, o groupby somente consegue agrupar valores iguais entre as colunas onde a distinção fica apenas no filtro, por exemplo: as colunas 'DENOM_CIA','CD_CONTA','DS_CONTA' elas contêm valores iguais entre elas, já a coluna 'VL_CONTA' contêm valores diferentes, mas no caso das datas, o groupby consegue agrupar mesmo que tenham valores diferentes, fiz um teste e setei em 'CD_CONTA' valores aleatórios e o groupby não agrupou. obrigado pelo seu tempo disponível, vou atrás de outros modos de agrupamentos/filtros

Answer (score 0):

No exemplo abaixo eu criei um pequeno `DataFrame` contendo duas colunas e quatro linhas.

A data de `3/10/2020` se repete duas vezes e é ela que será filtrada.

Criando o Dataframe

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"DT_REFER": ["1/10/2020", "2/10/2020", "3/10/2020", "3/10/2020"], 
                       "OUTRA": ["banana", "laranja", "abacaxi", "goiaba"]})

>>> df
    DT_REFER    OUTRA
0  1/10/2020   banana
1  2/10/2020  laranja
2  3/10/2020  abacaxi
3  3/10/2020   goiaba
```

Convertendo a coluna `DT_REFER` de `string` para `datetime`

```
>>> df["DT_REFER"] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT_REFER'], format="%d/%m/%Y")

>>> df
    DT_REFER    OUTRA
0 2020-10-01   banana
1 2020-10-02  laranja
2 2020-10-03  abacaxi
3 2020-10-03   goiaba
```

Filtrando pela data e jogando o resultado para um novo DataFrame

```
>>> new_df = df[(df["DT_REFER"] == "2020-10-03")]

>>> new_df
    DT_REFER    OUTRA
2 2020-10-03  abacaxi
3 2020-10-03   goiaba
```

**UPDATE**: Em tempo, para achar a data mais recente, basta pegar o valor máximo (`max`) da coluna `DT_REFER`

```
>>> recent_date = df['DT_REFER'].max()

>>> recent_date
Timestamp('2020-10-03 00:00:00')
```

**UPDATE**

Baseado em seus comentários, você pode:

```
>>> df
    DT_REFER    OUTRA    VERSAO
0 2020-10-01   banana 2020-10-05
1 2020-10-02  laranja 2020-10-06
2 2020-10-03  abacaxi 2020-10-10
3 2020-10-03   goiaba 2020-10-03

>>> new_df = df[(df["DT_REFER"] == df["DT_REFER"].max()) & (df["VERSAO"] == df["VERSAO"].max())]

>>> new_df
    DT_REFER    OUTRA    VERSAO
2 2020-10-03  abacaxi 2020-10-10
```

Note que o operador `&` representa `AND` e o operador `|` (não utilizado nesta query, representa `OR`

[Aqui](https://www.ritchieng.com/pandas-multi-criteria-filtering/) tem uma referência se quiser.

Espero que ajude

Comment: Paulo, essa seria a dificuldade, quando uso df['DT_REFER'].max() ele retorna as maiores datas, porém teria que ser um conjunto entre as colunas DT_FERER maiores e VERSAO maiores.

Comment: Veja se o update responde sua pergunta.

Comment: obrigado Paulo, vou testar, agradeço muito